Multinomial logistic regression: probability to represent the proportion of types in real population
I have a question about the probabiliy generated by the multinomial logistic model. I want to use the model to predict the proprotion of factory types in some cities. I have some independent variables from cities (e.g. infrastructure,labours and GDP etc). The dependent variables are the number of factory types in each sampled city (e.g. in city 1, I have 10 A type factory, 5 B type factory and 5 C type factory; in city 2, I have 5 A type factory, 8 B type factory and 7 C type factory, in city 3....). In total, the number of sampled cities are 30.
The current analysis was done by multinomial logistic model. The dataset structure was one row only has one depedent variables (e,g. ten rows have the same depedent variable factory type A with same independent variables as I have ten A type factory). In the results, I can see the model did a prediction about the probability of factory types, for example factory type A is 0.7, factory type b is 0.2 and factory type C is 0.1. My question is whether I can use the probability here to represent the proportion of factory types in cities.
Thank you very much in advance! Any alternative methods are welcome.
